# How do I get the selected value from a stored procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

When looking at a stored procedure, the logic seems to be "do stuff" followed by `select 1 as add_success`. How do I check that `add_success` value in C#?

#### Code

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) {
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("<sprocname>", connection)) {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(<a parameter>); // x10 or so
    connection.Open();
    var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // result is always -1, despite the sproc doing everything it is supposed to do (modify a few different tables)
```

#### Stored Procedure

```
// Do some stuff including inserts on a few different tables, then
INSERT INTO Table (field1, field2)
VALUES (@Val1, @Val2)

SELECT 1 AS add_success
```

It seems to be doing everything correctly, but the default return from `ExecuteNonQuery` is the affected rows and that is always `-1` even though all the operations appear to be completing successfully.

I also tried adding a parameter with a return value named `add_success` and `@add_success` but that also appeared to not work.

How do I return a value to C# from a stored procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You need to use `command.ExecuteScalar()`.
2. The result will be the first row of the first table in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` method instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)).